# With three divs, how to make one float to the right?

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, css-float

I have three divs:

```
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
<div class="C">C</div>
```

I want them to be positioned like this:

```
A     C
B
```

Where `C` should always be in the top right corner of the container they're in. How do I go about this in CSS using only the three divs and in that order?

I've tried a lot of different combinations of the `float`, `display` and `clear` properties to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can't be done by float, because it's no valid flow.

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.A {
  background: green;
}

.B {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.C {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

</style>




<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YGw3E/

Comment: `position: relative` on `.B` seems not to be needed?

Comment: However, this is the solution I went for! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please note that C overlaps A, this might be a problem. You can fix it by giving the element A and C fixed widths like 80% and 20% etc. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9phGH/

Answer (score 2):

This should work... if not please post a screenshot of the issue you have.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Initial response was flawed. I have amended to the below - there will be some browser restrictions but there are work-arounds to get the correct behaviour:

```
div {
    display:block;
    width:49%;
    float:left;   
    clear:left;
    }

div.C {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.a {
    float:left;
}

.b {
    clear:both;
}

.c {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

</style>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
<div class="b">B</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working because you've defined the classes A, B and C all upper case and setting the value to the lower case classes a, b and c.

Comment: @MAINERROR I've tested in FF 3.6, Chrome 6.0, Opera 10.61, IE6, IE7, IE8, all display as required. Of course it's good practise to always keep things in lowercase, though classname sensitivity isn't such an issue as e.g. id case.

Comment: Well I just wanted to point it out as it wasn't working that way trying it on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Ah jsfiddle. That thing is so buggy its almost unusable at times. Be very careful when using it. Certainly don't take anything on there as gospel! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If inrbob's example doesn't work for you, an alternative to float might be the following HTML;

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div><!-- /container -->
```

With this CSS;

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

div.C {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I do have a container, so that works! Thanks! (sled posted first, though)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried floating a,b to the left and c to the right? Also setting widths for your elements should help. Post some markup so we know what you have tried and how to fix it. very hard guessing these stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to rearrange them and have `A` float to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/78NnN/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't move the divs around. I don't have control over the HTML content.